# Counting the result LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using the following

```
var validLogin = from P in this.DataContext.Persons
                         where P.UserName.Equals(login) && P.Password.Equals(password)
            select new
            {
                P.FirstName,
                P.LastName,
                P.EmailAddress
            };
```

In this now i want to know, is there any result returned by this query? How to do this.

Comment: Aside: you've probably heard it before, but: try to avoid storing passwords (even encrypted) - for most purposes, a cryptographic, salted hash check is sufficient, without the security risks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `Count()` - use `Any()` unless you actually care about the count.

You can actually simplify this a lot, because you don't use the rest of the results either:

```
bool validLogin = DataContext.Persons.Any(p => p.UserName == login &&
                                               p.Password == password);
```

The nice thing about `Any()` is that whatever's processing the query can stop as soon as it's found *any* matching results - it doesn't need to keep looking for other potential matches. (`Count()` will *work* of course, it's just not as efficient, mostly because the operator itself isn't describing what you really care about as accurately.)

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
if (validLogin.Count() > 0) 
{
     //do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (validLogin.Count() > 0){}`